# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.4 when sending email using scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am making a task scheduler in Windows that sends an email whenever a warranty is due two months from now. I get an exception `Trying to get property of non-object` after I run `php artisan schedule:run` here is the command I created `SendEndRenewal.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Device;
use App\Mail\EndRenewal;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SendEndRenewal extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'send:renewals';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Email ending renewals';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $str = "";
        $devices = Device::whereYear('endDate','=',Carbon::now()->year)->whereMonth('endDate','=',Carbon::now()->month+2)->get();
        if (!empty($devices)) {
            foreach ($devices as $device) {
                Mail::to('vjztingson@gmail.com')->send(new EndRenewal($device));
                $str .= "sent " . $device->name . " ";
            }
        }
        $this->info($str);
    }
}
```

Here is my email object `EndRenewal.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Device;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EndRenewal extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $device;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Device $device)
    {
        $this->device = $device;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('devices.show', ['device'=>$this->device]);
    }
}
```

It works when I return a test blank page in `build()` in `EndRenewal.php` but it does not work when I pass an object and returns a view of the object. I tried the `protected $device` instead of public it still did not work. Please  help. Thank you!

I tried `print_r` the passed object it returns this

```
App\Device Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => serial
            [2] => endDate
            [3] => startDate
            [4] => renewal_id
        )
[connection:protected] => mysql
[table:protected] => 
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[keyType:protected] => int
[incrementing] => 1
[with:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[withCount:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[perPage:protected] => 15
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] => 
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Test Device 1 for Mail
        [startDate] => 2017-07-04
        [endDate] => 2017-09-04
        [created_at] => 2017-07-04 15:07:43
        [updated_at] => 2017-07-04 15:07:43
        [renewal_id] => 11
        [serial] => Test Device 1 for Mail
    )

[original:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Test Device 1 for Mail
        [startDate] => 2017-07-04
        [endDate] => 2017-09-04
        [created_at] => 2017-07-04 15:07:43
        [updated_at] => 2017-07-04 15:07:43
        [renewal_id] => 11
        [serial] => Test Device 1 for Mail
    )

[casts:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dates:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dateFormat:protected] => 
[appends:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[events:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[observables:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[relations:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[touches:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[timestamps] => 1
[hidden:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[visible:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[guarded:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )
```

)

Here is the view

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('pagetitle', 'Device Information')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/show.css">

<div class="container">

    <div class="flow">
        @if (Session::has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
        @endif
        @if (Session::has('error'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('error') }}</div>
        @endif
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Renewal Information</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <p><label>Company: </label>{{ $device->renewal->client->company }}</p>
                <p><label>Renewal Code: </label>{{ $device->renewal->code }}</p>
                <p><label>Contact Number: </label>{{ $device->renewal->client->contactNo }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        @if (Session::has('deviceMessage'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('deviceMessage') }}</div>
        @endif
        @if (Session::has('deviceError'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('deviceError') }}</div>
        @endif
        <div class="panel-heading">Device</div>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Serial</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$device->name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{$device->serial}}</td>
                    <td>{{$device->startDate}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{$device->endDate}}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editDevice" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Device</a>
                        @if (Auth::user()->type == 'Admin')
                            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['devices.destroy', $device, $device->renewal]]) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit('DELETE', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    @if (Auth::user()->type == 'Admin')
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Client Information</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <p><label>Company:</label>{{ $device->renewal->client->company }}</p>
                <p><label>Name:</label>{{$device->renewal->client->firstName}} {{str_limit($device->renewal->client->middleName, 1, '.')}} {{$device->renewal->client->lastName}}</p>
                <p><label>Contact No:</label>{{ $device->renewal->client->contactNo }}</p>
                <p><label>Address:</label>{{ $device->renewal->client->address }}</p>
                <p><label>Website:</label>{{ $device->renewal->client->website }}</p>
                <p><label>Industry:</label>{{ $device->renewal->client->industry }}</p>
                <a href="{{ route('clients.show', $device->renewal->client) }}" class="btn btn-info">View Profile</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade container" id="editDevice">
    {!! Form::model($device, [ 'method'=>'PUT', 'route' => ['devices.update', $device] ]) !!}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Device</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly', 'value'=>'{{ $device->name }}']) !!}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('serial', 'Serial Number:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('serial', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly', 'value'=>'{{ $device->serial }}']) !!}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('startDate', 'Warranty Start:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::date('startDate', null, ['value'=>'{{ $device->startDate }}']) !!}
                    &nbsp;
                    {!! Form::label('endDate', 'Warranty End:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::date('endDate', null, ['value'=>'{{ $device->endDate }}']) !!}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Submit </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: The error might be in your view , when you are trying to get the value from an object.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Will you upload your `view` file's code?

Comment: I'll look into it, but the view works except from Mail

Comment: renewal hasMany devices, devices belongsTo renewal

Comment: Try commenting the Auth & Session Block in your view and run it.

Comment: You call relationship return Eloquent Collection, it not a Object. You can't get value

Comment: it worked... but it seems i have to create a separate identical(without the Auth & Session and not extend the layout) since the variables in the layouts became undefined

Comment: You have to pass the user model as well with the view to access it .

Comment: @vladjamir try dd($this->device->renewal->client->company) and show me error or not

Comment: @mydo47 there is no error regarding the device. Zeus is right about the errors. this email is triggered by windows task scheduler and I don't know how to pass the current authenticated user model when it clicks since this view should be by an admin user